# During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Could you please get me where I am going wrong in the below code. I am new in python. Even i call the pandas core library. While calling the function i got error at last.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import Bounds
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from google.colab import files
from pandas._libs.index import IndexEngine
from pandas._libs.hashtable import PyObjectHashTable
f= files.upload()
df=pd.read_excel(r'symbol.xlsx',index_col='date',parse_dates=True)
df.head()
dir(df)
m=3
def get_edges(df, m):
  edges = {}
  series = df.columns
  for s in series:
    std = df[s].std()
    edges[s] = [std * (-m / 2 + x) for x in range(m + 1)]
    if edges[s][0] > df[s].min():
      edges[s] = edges[s][1:]
      edges[s].insert(0, df[s].min())
    if edges[s][-1] < df[s].max():
      edges[s] = edges[s][:-1]
      edges[s].append(df[s].max())
  return edges
edges = get_edges(df,m)
g = pd.DataFrame()
for key, value in edges.items(): 
  g[key] = pd.cut(df[key],value,labels=False, include_lowest=True)
def get_p(g, m):
  list_ = []
  for i in range(m):
    for j in range(m):
      list_.append([i,j])
  index_col = ['i','j']
  p_index = pd.DataFrame(list_, columns=index_col)
  series = g.columns
  f = lambda x: x/x.sum()
  list_ = []
  for beta in series:
    for alpha in series:
      p = pd.concat([g[beta],g[alpha].shift(-1)],axis=1)[:-1].astype(dtype='int')
      p.columns = index_col
      p = pd.DataFrame(p.groupby(index_col).size(),columns=['freq']).reset_index()
      p = p.merge(p_index, on=index_col, how='right').fillna(0)
      p[f'p{beta}_{alpha}'] = p['freq'].groupby(p[i]).transform(f)
      p = p.drop('freq', axis=1).set_index(index_col)
      list_.append(p)
  return pd.concat(list_, axis=1)
ge=get_p(g,m)
print(ge)
```

My dataset looks like. It is time series based dataset. Bid and fut are the log price of two markets.

```
    bid fut
date        
2020-05-04 09:15:01 9.810001    9.811235
2020-05-04 09:15:02 9.806426    9.807802
2020-05-04 09:15:03 9.803253    9.802976
2020-05-04 09:15:04 9.804358    9.805047
2020-05-04 09:15:05 9.805047    9.80794
```

Here is the error part. It is showing an unusal error even after giving the right input.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 2
```

Comment: Can you pinpoint the line number in your code where the error occurred.

Comment: Actually i get error in the last line while calling the function.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. I'm asking where exactly in the function is it giving this error

Comment: Function is running with no error. But the problem comes while calling it.

Comment: The number of parameters and syntax for function call seems fine. Keyerror comes normally in case of incorrect indexing in for loop(which is inside the function). So,Please check once again.

Comment: Thanks. It is solved.In the body of function there is some error.